# What is physical significance of $k$-space topology?

Tags: topology, skyrmion

I am working with topological materials and I do understand what topology is. While reading papers, I am not able to understand the "nontrivial k-space topology". How skyrmions are mostly realized in metallic ferromagnetic materials that do not exhibit a distinct nontrivial k-space topology.
What exactly mean by non-trivial k space topology? and how we can observe it in materials? not only in mathematical terms.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to your understanding of topology, specifically as it relates to condensed matter physics?

Comment: Topology is the study of properties of systems that remain unchanged as the system is continuously bent, twisted, or otherwise deformed. One class of materials, which have holes cannot be turned back into materials that have no holes. so there exist topological invariant. The idea about the nature of topological invariant depends on their dimensionality, Time reversal symmetry, particle-hole symmetry, etc. This topological invariant is written as Chern number in topological materials.

Answer (score -1):

topology, algebraic topology to be precise, rougly studies two problems.

1. smooth and continous deformability of a manifold(for our purposes you can think this as a surface or a loop). e.g. can we deform a donut to a sphere smooth and ina continous and reversable manner? we can't because their genus or the number of holes they have is different. The rigours term for deformaing a minofld to another manilofd in a smooth and continuous  etc. manner is homeomorphism. in other words we say that sphere is not homeo morphic to a torus.
2. now let's discuss second problem algebraic topology studies.  before that remember  the definition of a maping. mapping $f$ is the usual function which takes an argument and gives an output according to this argument. in other word it maps elements of one set to elements of another set. e.g. let's define $f(x)=x^2$ and let's set the domain of $f$ as $\mathbb{R}$ and the image will be also $\mathbb{R}$. In other words $f$ takes any real number and gives another real number as an output. So it is a mappinf from real numbers to real numbers. in other words we denote this as, $$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$$.
   Now, we can define mappings from a manifold to another manifold. The second problem topology interested in is, wheter we can deform smoothly etc a mapping to another mappig. This is called homotopy.

Now let's assume we have an hamiltonian of a 2d system in k-space $h(k)$. Now since we have periodic boundary conditions the allowed $k$ points forms a torus($\mathbb{T}^2$).

now the hamiltonian is then a mapping
$$h:\mathbb{T}^2\to M$$
now the what we look is wheter a given mapping can be deformed to another mapping homotpicaly or not. Trivial topology means that, the mapping(hamiltonian) can be deformed to  a trivial mapping.  one thing  determines wheter h is trivial or not is the chern number.

so this is one thing what they mean my trivial topology in k space. chern number is usually related to conductivity.

Comment: thank you so much.  I got it.